# "Catastrophic failure" when accessing an OCX library from C#

Tags: c#, interop, activex, ocx

I'm currently trying to use a third-party DLL from my C# application. I've registered the DLL and added it as a reference from the list of COM component. As I understand, this should create the necessary interop classes to access this DLL from C#.

On attempting to call any methods from within the DLL I get the following exception:-

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException was unhandled
 Message=Catastrophic failure (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000FFFF (E_UNEXPECTED))
 Source=mscorlib
 ErrorCode=-2147418113
 StackTrace:
  at System.RuntimeType.ForwardCallToInvokeMember(String memberName, BindingFlags flags, Object target, Int32[] aWrapperTypes, MessageData& msgData)
  at OCXDLL._OCXDLL.MyMethod(Int32 param0, String param1, String param2, String param3, Int32 param4)
  at MyApplication.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\MyApplication\Program.cs:line 29
  at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
  at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
  at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
  at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
  at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
  at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
  at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
 InnerException:
```

And the code I'm using to call the library:-

```
using OCXDLL;

namespace MyApplication
{
 class Program
 {
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
   OCXDLL libObj = new OCXDLL();
   libObj.MyMethod(....); 
  }
 }
}
```

Note that this is not an ActiveX control (for which I have seen a number of solutions to fix this problem).

Does anyone have any ideas as to where I'm going wrong?

Thanks

Comment: I too have been banging my head with the "Catastrophic failure" (WTF? Have we been hit by a meteorite?!), but my error appears and disappears randomly. Launching the project 10 times in a row (without edits or recompiles) gives the error about two times. Who knows... :|

Comment: That is strange. Controls often return E_UNEXPECTED when called on the wrong thread, but it doesn't look like you've got any strange threading logic here. I would be calling up that third party and asking them if they're familiar with the issue.

Comment: We have had these issues with very old legacy third party com API's before, we have always had to contact the vendor and get them to sort it, without the source code it is very hard to know..

Comment: Running on Windows 7? I found that one of my legacy libraries refuses to run with DEP enabled. Try bcdedit.exe {current} /set nx alwaysoff to get an idea if this is your problem or not.

Comment: Eric - yup, no multi-threading involved. This was just a simple console app to try and get the library to work.

Jason - I'm developing on Windows XP.

Thanks for the suggestions and thoughts everyone. I've decided to write my own implementation of the library. It's going to be quicker than waiting for the vendor to try and fix what ever is going wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Solved For Me!

I had the same problem for about two weeks!!!

I was trying to create an instance from my ocx in c#. the object was successfully created but I was unable to call its methods with the damn Catastrophic Exception.

```
 xPKTBLib.xPKTB p = new xPKTBLib.xPKTB()
```

As you see I was trying to create an instance from the main object and call its methods but its Not the right thing to do!
When you create a MFC project, two interfaces are generated automatically and you use them to declare your methods for inbound or outbound calls. One with _D prefix (in my case as _DxPKTB) and one with _D prefix and Events post-fix (_DxPKTBEvents).

When you want to call the Activex methods in c# you have to create an instance from it's interface and then call the methods instead of calling the base object's methods directly!

```
  xPKTBLib._DxPKTB p = new xPKTBLib.xPKTB();
```

this trick worked for me. Hope to be useful for you too...

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio

Click on TOOLs->OPTIONS->DEBUGGING

Disable just my code(Managed only)

under this Warn if no user code on launch

It's work for me.