# How to pass values to this method?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an dll in that class the following method

```
 [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.PreserveSig | MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime)]
    bool SetIPAddress([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)] ref string lpszIPAddress, int dwPortNumber, int dwPassWord);
```

**How do I pass values to this method:**

```
public FP_CLOCKLib._DFP_CLOCK   ff = new FP_CLOCKLib.FP_CLOCK();
```

reffered to create instance like ["Catastrophic failure" when accessing an OCX library from C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5650883/catastrophic-failure-when-accessing-an-ocx-library-from-c-sharp#14438573)

```
bool status = ff.SetIPAddress(ref ip, 5005, 0);
```

it threw error

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x8000FFFF): Catastrophic
>   failure (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000FFFF (E_UNEXPECTED)) at
>   System.RuntimeType.ForwardCallToInvokeMember(String memberName,
>   BindingFlags flags, Object target, Int32[] aWrapperTypes, MessageData&
>   msgData) at FP_CLOCKLib.FP_CLOCKClass.SetIPAddress(String&
>   lpszIPAddress, Int32 dwPortNumber, Int32 dwPassWord)

Comment: [Click on TOOLs **->** OPTIONS **->** DEBUGGING **->** Disable just my code(Managed only)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5650883/catastrophic-failure-when-accessing-an-ocx-library-from-c-sharp)

Comment: You need to provide additional details in your question, like how you are preparing the 'ip' variable to use as parameter, if is a COM object (and its threading model), a pure DLL or really an OCX..  all these matters.

Answer (score 1):

This could be your issue, the following steps could help.

> This problem is a cryptic manifestation of a known issue with
>   URLMON.dll. KB945701 -
>   http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;945701
>
> We performed the following fix which resolved the issue:

1. Click Start
2. click Run
3. type regedit
4. then click OK
5. Locate and then click the following registry subkey: 
   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet
   Explorer\MAIN\FeatureControl\FEATURE_IGNORE_ZONES_INITIALIZATION_FAILURE_KB945701

> Note If the FEATURE_IGNORE_ZONES_INITIALIZATION_FAILURE_KB945701
>   subkey does not exist, you must manually create it

6. Right-click FEATURE_IGNORE_ZONES_INITIALIZATION_FAILURE_KB945701 ,
   point to New, and then click DWORD Value
7. Type w3wp.exe to name the new registry entry
8. then press ENTER
9. Right-click w3wp.exe
10. then click Modify
11. In the Value data box
12. type 1
13. then click OK
14. Exit Registry Editor.
15. Restart the system

https://forums.iis.net/t/1148764.aspx?Catastrophic+failure+Exception+from+HRESULT+0x8000FFFF+E_UNEXPECTED+